# Is there any way of calling a gui element from AppDelegate in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, google-signin

I'm implementing a google sign in feature in my mobile ios swift app and all the action there is handled by `AppDelegate.swift`. I want to show the loading indicator while the logging in process takes place, so in my `UIViewController` I attached a very simple code to the google sign in button:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBAction func googleSignInButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
}
```

Now when user taps a sign in button it automatically shows the spinning indicator and opens safari view to ask for log in credentials. When user types them in, he is redirected again to the `UIViewController` (now with spinning indicator turned on - so that's great) and the whole process in `AppDelegate` takes place:

```
 func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Looks like we have a sign in error: \(error)")
        }else {
            //here I'm sending the google token to my backend server and in case of
            //success I'm redirecting user to the protected panel - 
            //main window of my app:

              let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
              if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabController") as? TabController {
              self.window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC

          }
```

The code above happens in `AppDelegate`, so my question is - how, from that place, I can refer to the loading indicator in `ViewController` and stop spinning it in case of success?

Comment: I might make a case for not presenting the spinner in the first place.

Comment: The thing is sometimes the logging part takes up to several seconds (especially when the internet connection is poor) - in that case user still stares at the logging screen and when there is no spinner at all he might be quite confused. Even I, as the author of the app, sometimes stare at the screen thinking what the hell is going on and then I realize that oh, it's just the poor internet here... So I want to add a loading indicator so that the user is notified and entertained during the waiting time...

Comment: Post an NSNotification and have your view controller subscribe to that

Comment: Why did you put that code in AppDelegate? You could put it in the view controller or in a separate class. Anyway from the code above I see that the view controller with the spinner gets replaced when signed in. Then why do you care about the spinner?

Comment: @Jelly I put the code in AppDelegate because it's the official way that google suggest, check it out https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift#enable_sign-in Anyway, I care about the spinner because there might be a situation when user on safari view ( http://i.stack.imgur.com/1ejAR.png ) clicks deny and then he comes back to the same view controller where the spinner is already running :) And in that case the spinner should be gone, therefore I want to hide it from AppDelegate

Comment: Well, it kinda makes sense of having that in app delegate because it also holds your login state from what I see in the link above. Anyway I would go with the solution suggested by @Paulw11.

Comment: @nhgrif but the knowledge about completion of loading comes from appdelegate, so that's why I want to know how to reach spinner from there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift#enable_sign-in), the `GIDSignIn` singleton has two different delegate properties.

Google recommends that your app's `AppDelegate` implement the `GIDSignInDelegate` protocol and make the `AppDelegate` be the `delegate`.

But what you have overlooked is that there is also a `GIDSignInUIDelegate`.  Your appropriate view controller(s) should implement [this protocol](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/protocol_g_i_d_sign_in_u_i_delegate-p), and most likely, on their `viewWillAppear` method, assign themselves as the `GIDSignIn` singleton's `uiDelegate`.